# Powershell script fails on running psql command

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I'm trying to run a script on a new file with Powershell. Script I got internet looks like this.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "c:\folder_to_lookat"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "COPY new FROM '$path' DELIMITER '#';"
    Write-Host "New File indicated"
            Clear-content C:\script_to_run.txt
    $script = Get-Content C:\original_script.txt
    $script[0] = $logline
    $script | Out-File C:\script_to_run.txt
    psql -d postgres -U postgres -w -c "\i C:\script_to_run.txt"
    Write-Host "New file caculated!"
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

This script checks if there is any new file in the folder. If there is, run script with psql to do something. However, there are some problems.

1. It gives me multiple
          Write-Host "New File indicated"
          Write-Host "New file caculated!"
   for single new file in the folder. This really shouldn't have to happen.
2. psql script doesn't run. 
               psql -d postgres -U postgres -w -c "\i C:\script_to_run.txt"
   This part.

Even though it gives me multiple write-host, nothing has happen in Postgres. Not a single change. script_to_run.txt script is quiet long and requires few second to finish.

psql Line itself runs very well if I just type it and don't use any powershell script for it.

[Picture of Powershell running psql script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FafHi.png)

Is there some kinda thing I'm missing? (Like fflush) I'm new to Powershell and just not sure about anything.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Your postgres instance doesn't require password authentication?

Comment: Yes, when I just type it on powershell. It just runs very smoothly.

Comment: Additionally, running script with just psql works fine. ex) psql -d postgres -U postgres -w -c "\i C:/CRCDB/log.txt"
psql -d postgres -U postgres -w -c "\i C:/CRCDB/script.txt"
I don't know why checking new things in folder causes problems.